# A question about defining a classical CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

This is kind of related to this,
[Defining a CFT using beta-functions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53768/defining-a-cft-using-beta-functions)

So what would be the right definition of a CFT even classically?

- Is it true that classically one will call a theory scale invariant only if the action is invariant under scale transformations? (and not by the Lagrangian density)

For example under the scale transformations $x' = \lambda x$, in $3+1$ the scalar field goes as $\phi'(x') = \lambda \phi(x)$ and in $1+1$ it goes as $\phi'(x') = \phi (x)$. This means that in $3+1$ the action of the massless scalar field is not scale invariant but in $1+1$ it is but the Lagrangian density goes the otherway. But from the point of view of beta-functions isn't it more consistent to call the $1+1$ theory as a CFT but not the one in $3+1$?

Isn't a massless scalar field theory in $3+1$ guaranteed to produce mass by RG flow whereas the $1+1$ theory will not?

Answer (score 1):

A classical field theory is said to be conformally invariant iff the action is left invariant under the action of the conformal transformations (as usual when we define a symmetry of a theory).
The action for the free massless scalar field is invariant under scale transformations in any dimensions because the (classical) scaling dimension for the scalar field is taken to be $(d-2)/2$.
In the interacting case (but still classical), it is enough for the couplings to be dimensionless to ensure scale invariance. So for exemple in four dimensions, you can have only $\phi^4$ interactions. In any cases, a mass term will always break scale invariance.

For the quantum aspects, it is good to keep in mind that generically, a classical interacting conformal theory will not remains conformal after quantization (in particular, this is true also in two dimensions, answering  one of your questions). Typically, to define the quantum theory one need to introduce a UV-cutoff, and this will generically trigger some non-trivial RG flow, breaking scale invariance.
I think the answer to the previous question [Defining a CFT using beta-functions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53768/defining-a-cft-using-beta-functions) contains good elements on this discussion, so I shall refrain to reproduce it here.

I hope this help !

Comment: I didn't understand your comment about the action being scale invariant for a massless scalar in any dimension. That was the point of my question - under $x' = \lambda x$, $\phi'(x') = \lambda \phi(x)$, $\int d^4x (\partial _\mu \phi(x))^2$ is not scale invariant. The action in primed variables is $\lambda ^4$ times the unprimed one - it comes from the measure (though the Lagrangian density is covariant)

Comment: The Lagrangian density has mass dimension $4$, that's easy to see: $[\partial_\mu] = [\phi] = 1$ (in 4D). So the action, including the measure, will be invariant.

Comment: Actually there is a mistake in your formula, user6818. In four dimensions, $\phi'(\lambda x)=\lambda^{-1} \phi (x)$.

Comment: @Bru Ah! Here I guess the power of $\lambda$ is being determined by trying to ensure that as a $1-form$, $\phi'(x')dx' = \phi(x)dx$..right? In general for a primary operator of weight $(h,\bar{h})$ one would want $A(z',\bar{z}')(dz')^h (d\bar{z}')^{\bar{h}} = A(z,\bar{z})dz d\bar{z}$ So for every $d$ I guess one will have to first derive the values of $h$ and $\bar{h}$ such that one can satisfy $h + \bar{h} = mass\text{ }dimension$ and $h - \bar{h} = spin$..right?

Comment: Typo: It should be $A(z',\bar{z}')(dz')^h d\bar{z}')^{\bar{h}} = A(z,\bar{z})(dz)^h (d\bar{z})^{\bar{h})$ But then for the scalar field in $d$ dimensions one would be forced to have $h = \bar{h} = \frac{d-2}{4}$. Now for $d=4$ we get $h = \bar{h} = \frac{1}{2}$ - now what sense does $(dz)^{1/2}$ make? How can one recover the $\lambda \phi'(x') = \phi(x)$ from here?

Comment: Also in $d=4$ this classically conformal massless scalar is not a CFT because RG flow would produce the mass. But in $d=2$ what exactly protects such a quantum breakdown of the symmetry?

Comment: Dear user6818, in higher dimensions things don't work that way, i.e. conformal mappings don't factorize into [anti]holomorphic mappings and we don't use $h$ and $\bar{h}$. Spins are just the labels of the Lorentz group, which tell you how the field transforms, and the mass dimension $\Delta$ is a free parameter.

Comment: ...and in $D=4$, the free massless scalar is definitely a CFT on the quantum level. The theory doesn't flow! Equivalently, how could a quantum correction break conformal invariance?

Comment: If you don't find this convincing, you might take some time to study the classics, such as the book by Ferrara, Gatto and Grillo from the 70s: http://inspirehep.net/record/86694. It's very rigorous in terms of the algebra and these guys understood conformal symmetry very early on. Also look for papers by Mack, Salam and Lüscher.

Comment: @Vibert It was a very stupid mistake on my part!Surely the $(h,\bar{h})$ definition I made is valid only in $1+1$. So in $1+3$ how would one define a primary/quasi-primary operator and its weight? Even for this simple case of massless scalar field how does one derive its conformal transformation in arbitrary dimensions? I mean how could one have derived this $\lambda \phi'(x') = \phi(x)$?

Comment: @Vibert Since the mass-term preserves all the symmetries of the kinetic term, how can one possibly prevent it from showing up in the RG flow? Isn't a RG flow guaranteed to produce all terms which preserve the symmetry?

Comment: Spin and dimension are given by transformation laws, which are tedious to state but straightforward. In general, these laws are of the form "scale factor * Lorentz matrices which act on the indices." There's a Mack + Lüscher paper which classifies all reps of the conformal group, if you're interested. The free scalar has dimension $(D-2)/2$, which is just its mass dimension and you derive it by studying the Lagrangian. How can a scalar transform in some other way than $\phi(x) \rightarrow \lambda^{\alpha} \phi(x)$ for some $\alpha$?

Comment: @user6818: I think there is some confusion in your messages. A mass term will automatically break conformal invariance, as it introduce a mass scale in the theory. Moreover, the very notion of RG flow is intrinsically quantum-mechanical, and thus it is meaningless to talk about RG flows in a classical theory. Finally, a free quantum theory never runs. These three facts should be usefull to solve some puzzles you raised.

Comment: Also, RG flow is something you can *calculate*. It tells you how couplings depend on the scale $\mu$. Just open a textbook on the subject (which will undoubtedly talk extensively about $\phi^4$ theory) and try to transpose the discussion to the free scalar.

Comment: @Vibert What I am saying is this - if $\Delta$ is the mass dimension of an operator $O$ then that it transforms under scaling as $O'(x') = \lambda ^{-\Delta} O(x)$ is true may be under the assumption that the RG flow of the mass has a fixed point at 0 mass. (..but is this massless fixed point guaranteed to exist when the theory is interacting?..) How generically can be equate the mass dimension to the scaling dimension?

Comment: I mean that in a weakly coupled CFT, mass dimension = scaling dimension. This is esp. true for the free scalar. In a strongly coupled CFT, I don't even know how to define the mass dimension, but the notion of scaling dimension is the same as in the weakly coupled case. Next, in general there's no FP at zero mass (just think of Wilson-Fischer).

Comment: @Vibert Thanks! Now that you say that in general there is no FP at 0 mass then how do you find the relationship between $O'(x')$ and $O(x)$? Thats what I am asking - given an operator what is the method of finding its change under dialtions/conformal transformation? (...this using of the mass dimension as scaling dimension will work only if the massless theory is a fixed point and one is sitting there..)

Comment: That relation ($O \mapsto O' = \lambda^{-\Delta}O$) is always true: it's just the transformation law for scalars, and $\Delta$ depends on the theory/FP. That's the mathematics of the conformal group- for a generic CFT, there's no Lagrangian you can read this off from, and even for weakly coupled FP's there are anomalous dimensions, so you cannot trust naive power counting to find $\Delta$.